# Replacing items in a python list based on their current value

Tags: python, list, colors

I want to generate a list with two alternating values, but they do not alternate with a regular frequency. I have generated a list that contains 1's and 0's. Wherever there is a 1, I want the first new value, and wherever there is a 0, I want the second. I have this block of code that will work, but it doesn't seem very clever to me. Is there a nicer way to do this?

```
for k in range(len(colourMap)):
if(colourMap[k]):
    colourMap[k] = '#72DE18'
else:
    colourMap[k] = '#DE1899'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
colourMap = ['#72DE18' if i else '#DE1899' for i in colourMap]
```